# Cannot find module "./cms-management/cms.module

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, angular6

```
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [

    { path: '', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule'`enter code here` },
    { path: 'manage-pages', loadChildren: './cms-management/user-management/user.module#UsersModule'},
    { path: 'manage-users', loadChildren: './user-management/user.module#UsersModule'}


]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Above one is the my app-routing module code. then i have cms module like below-

```
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { CmsComponenent } from './cms-management.component';
import { CmsService } from '../services/cms.service';
import { CmsRoutingModule } from './cms-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CmsComponenent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    CmsRoutingModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ],
  providers: [
    CmsService
  ],
})
export class CmsModule { }
```

And finally i have cms-routing module like below-

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CmsComponenent } from './cms-management.component';


const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: CmsComponenent }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})

export class CmsRoutingModule{}
```

Now i am doing same for usermodule but not getting any error while when i try for cms i get the error. below one is the exact error which is occuring for me

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "./cms-management/user-management/user.module".

Does anybody have any idea how i can get rid of this. I am already using relative path as shown in code itself. angular cli version is 6 and angular version is 6 as well

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Post the code itself. We can't copy-paste from an image to try it out for ourselves.

Comment: As per your requirement, i have added required code. Please help me out

Comment: I apologized for wasting your precious time on it. I rectified the issue and it was hyphen missing in the folder name. everything else was correct. I ruined my hours. Anyways, thanks for looking into it.